# Pythonの正規表現の"{m,n}?"の挙動について

Tags: python, 正規表現

次のようなスクリプトがあった場合、私が思っていた結果は"**aab**"なのですが、"**aaaab**"が返ってきてしまいます。

```
s = "aaaab"
pattern = r"a{2,4}?b"

match = re.search(pattern, s)
if match is not None:
    print(match.group(0))
```

patternを **r"a{2,4}?"** にすると"**aa**"が返ってくるのに **r"a{2,4}?b"** だとaの数が4つになるのが気持ち悪いです。
これはPythonのバグなのでしょうか。公式ドキュメントには"少なく 繰り返したものとマッチする"と書かれているのですが。。

バージョンは 2.7.11 です。
(バージョン3ではどのような挙動になるのかも、教えていただけると助かります。)

Comment: `r"a{2,4}?b"` で `search()` だと、「aが指定回数連続したあとに**bが存在する**文字列があったときにそれを返す」なのでそれが正しい挙動です。aの数を揃えたいのなら、`sub()` などで置き換えないといけないですね。

Comment: 文字列 `s` は左から右へスキャンされますので、正規表現の先頭に `.*` を置けば(`r'.*(a{2,4}?b)'`)期待する結果にはなります。ただ、この場合は `match.group(1)` とする必要がありますけれども。

Comment: @metropolis さんの正規表現は私も一時回答に書いていたですが、その書き方は `aab` が複数あったときの挙動が面倒なことに気付きました（なので、質問者さんがどのくらいの文字列を求めているかによります）。

Comment: 皆様、ご回答ありがとうございます。理解できました。今回は、後輩に正規表現を教えている最中に、"{m , n}?"の挙動に疑問をもったため投稿させていただきました。普段使わない書式というのもありますが、search()の挙動を再確認する必要もありますね。。皆様のご協力ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

バグではありません。

Python 2、Python 3、および Perl の正規表現は、デフォルトでは**最左**・最長マッチをするようになっています。`?` をつけることで最長マッチが最短マッチに変わりますが、最左マッチであることは変わりません。また、最左マッチが最短マッチより優先します。このため今回の差が生まれます。

より具体的に言うと、`a{2,4}?b`という正規表現は、最初の `a` がマッチした**後**に `a` の回数を最小にしようとします。したがって 1 文字目の `a` にマッチした後「`b` のマッチに失敗し、`a` のマッチに成功する」を 3 回繰り返し、最後に `b` にマッチするという挙動になります。

したがって、これはバグではありません。`re` パッケージは正しく最も少ない回数マッチしていますが、その開始地点は最左になるという訳です。

<sub>（ところで、そもそも今回の正規表現では最初から `aab` や `a{2}b` という正規表現でマッチすれば良さそうです。おそらく質問者さんには固有の背景があってこのような書き方になったのかと思いますが。）</sub>

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。理解できました。今回は、後輩に正規表現を教えている最中に、"{m , n}?"の挙動に疑問をもったため投稿させていただきました。普段使わない書式というのもありますが、search()の挙動を再確認する必要もありますね。。確かに、"a{2}b"で事足りるので、実際にスクリプトを書く際はそのように書くことになると思います。ご協力ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

`search()`の仕様からこのような挙動になります。

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#re.search

> string を走査し、正規表現 pattern がマッチを生じさせる最初の場所を探して

文字列の左端から順々にマッチするかどうか試して、マッチした時点で終了します。マッチ開始位置が0に近いものが優先されるわけです。

もし希望の動作が欲しいなら、`search()`は使えません。すべての位置からのマッチを記録して、マッチした長さが最小のものを選びます。